# Symfony2 entity type check box set preferred choices

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I have the following form filed in the edit form.

```
->add('district', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'AdminBundle:Districts',
                               'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) {
                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                    ->where('c.status =:status')
                                    ->setparameter('status','1');
            },
                    'property' => 'districtName',
                    'preferred_choices' => array($details->getDistrict()),
                    'multiple' => TRUE,
                    'expanded' => TRUE,
                    'required' => true,

                        )
                )
```

Output of this is checkboxes. I can check more districts here.
In the edit mode how to set the preferred choices?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand your question.  Do you want to define more of your Districts as preferred (rather than just the currently selected one as in your example), so that they go to the top of the list?

Comment: yes want to checked more districts

Comment: OK, I still don't understand, sorry!  I hope Matthew A Thomas's answer gives you what you want (he describes how to make certain options "preferred", i.e. move them to the top of the list, only in edit mode (although the Symfony docs suggest that `preferred_choices` isn't really for checkboxes like here)).  If you want something else, then maybe you could edit your question to include examples of what you get currently, and what you want to get instead?

Answer (score 1):

OK, you need to use an EventListener against the form. See documentation for more information.

This will allow you to pre set form data

Example ()

/* Form */

```
 namespace Company\YourBundle\Form\Type;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
 use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
 use Company\YourBundle\Form\EventListener\YourEventListener;

 class FormType extends AbstractType {

     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
         $builder->addEventSubscriber(new YourEventListener($builder->getFormFactory()));
     }

     public function getName() {
         return 'company_formtype';
     }

}
```

/* Event Listener (You may require to pass more data to this class from your form as I have little information to help you with)*/

```
 namespace Company\YourBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class ActivityListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

private $form;

public function __construct($form) {
    $this->form = $form;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'onPreSetData',
    );
}

public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $e) {
    $data = $e->getData();
    $form = $e->getForm();

    if ($form->has('district')) {
        $form->remove('district');
    }

    $form->add($this->form->createNamed('district', 'entity', null, array(
                        'class' => 'AdminBundle:Districts',
                           'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) {
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->where('c.status =:status')
                                ->setparameter('status','1')},
                                'property' => 'districtName',
                'preferred_choices' => $data['id'] ? /** in edit mode set the preferred **/ ? null,
                'multiple' => TRUE,
                'expanded' => TRUE,
                'required' => true,

                    ));
      }

 }
```